# How well will LED strips hold up in a kitchen?

Tags: lighting, kitchens, led

I am planning to install LED strip light in my parents kitchen. We have a chimney that is blocking out all the light over the stove top.

The things I am worried about is

1. Longevity of the lights. I don't visit them often and I want the lights to last long and not fail in a few months or weeks.
2. Resistance to oil and grime. and how easy it is to clean.
3. Heat and short circuit. I saw some of the post that said that the heat melted the wires and shorted. I know led's don't heat much. But I never used LED strip

Comment: Longevity of leds should be multiple years under normal usage. Is there a reason you're talking about strips rather than Edison-base bulbs?

Comment: LED's have a much longer rated life. Depending on the model you get, they likely can come with a weather coating. This would allow them to simply wipe them down if they get oily. The LED's will run much cooler than any other bulk out there. How much heat will there be where you want to install these?

Comment: Okay great. Any other thing to make sure that it doesn't cause any fire hazard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Longevity:* LED's are generally marketed between 50k-100k hours of burn-time. I installed them throughout my home 18 months ago; none of them have failed yet.

*Grime Resistance:* For a kitchen, buy waterproof strip lights [like these](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005EHHLD8) - they'll hold up against steam. You can also fabricate an easy-to-clean cover using clear PVC and brackets

*Heat*: If the strips are installed correctly, each LED will be cool to the touch. Monitor the installation for excess heat and wire in a resistor if needed.

Comment: 50-100k hours is unrealistic. http://www.electrobob.com/led-logger-v3/